# How do I check to see if tk_getOpenfile actually opened a file?

Tags: tcl

this part of my program opens a file for downloading onto a scanner to flash it. if i just close out of the file selection window i get this error message-

```
wrong # args: should be cksum ?-format string? -channel chan | -filename file | string
wrong # args: should be cksum ?-format string? -channel chan | -filename file | string
    while executing
"::crc::cksum -file $file2program"


set file2program [tk_getOpenFile]

## determine chsum
set filechecksum1 [::crc::cksum -file $file2program]
set filechecksum [format %X [scan $filechecksum1 %d]]
.flashutility.messagearea insert end "Checksum for binary file = $filechecksum\n"
.flashutility.messagearea see end
set filesize [file size $file2program]
.flashutility.messagearea insert end "Size of the file to transfer is $filesize bytes\n"
.flashutility.messagearea see end
update
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tk_getOpenFile` command doesn't open the file. It returns the fully-qualified name of the file to open. If the user cancels, it returns the empty string, which is not the same as any fully-qualified filename on any platform.